# docker-compose succeed but server does not response when request

Tags: docker-compose, no-response

I have built a RESTful API web service using **Flask** framework, **Redis** as main database, **MongoDB** as a backup store and **Celery** as task queue to store data into MongoDB in background

Then I dockerize my application using **docker-compose**. Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
  mongo:
    image: "mongo:3.6.5"
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: syncapp
```

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
# base image
FROM python:3.5-alpine
MAINTAINER xhoix <145giakhang@gmail.com>

# copy just the requirements.txt first to leverage Docker cache
# install all dependencies for Python app
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app

# install dependencies in requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy all content to work directory /app
COPY . /app

# specify the port number the container should expose
EXPOSE 5000

# run the application
CMD ["python", "/app/app.py"]
```

After run command `docker-compose up`, the app server, Redis and Mongo server just run well. But when I use **Postman** or **curl** to call the API, for example `http://127.0.0.1:5000/sync/api/v1.0/users`, which should return JSON format of all users, but the result is `Could not get any response: There was an error connecting to http://127.0.0.1:5000/sync/api/v1.0/users.`

I have no idea why this happens.
Thanks for any help and suggestion!

Comment: Have you tried adding `network_mode: host` option to docker compose services?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the cause of the issue:

After an hour debug, it turns out that I only need to change the app host to `0.0.0.0`. Maybe when mapping port, docker default will be 0.0.0.0, since when I run command `docker-compose ps`, the PORTS column of each container has format `0.0.0.0:<port> -> <port>`. I don't know this is the cause of the issue or not, but I did it and the problem is solved

Comment: I wish that I had only spent an hour debugging this like you did. :) Thanks for posting this for the world to see.

Answer (score 0):

If operating system Linux then use :

> ifconfig -a

If operating system Windows then use :

> ipconfig /all

Then check the interface like docker or something with virtualization, and use the ipv4 or inet

Or Just use the docker command:

> docker network inspect bridge

Then use the gateway ip on IPAM